# AutoMapper Include does not work as expected?

Tags: c#, automapper

I (am forced to) use AutoMapper **[version 1.1.0.188](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)**. I have a base class *SchufaBaseFeature* and a derived class *SchufaFeature*.

```
public partial class SchufaFeature : SchufaBaseFeature
{//some code here}
```

Why is Include not working as I would expect it to ?

This is what I have done with AutoMapper (Mapping to DataBase):

```
 //TODO include does not work as it should!
        Mapper.CreateMap<SchufaBaseFeature, CFSCHUFAFEATURE>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.FEATUREWITHOUTBIRTHDATE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetSpecified(EnumToBool(src.featureWithoutBirthdate), src.featureWithoutBirthdateSpecified)))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.OWNFEATURE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetSpecified(src.ownFeature, src.ownFeatureSpecified)))
              .Include<SchufaFeature, CFSCHUFAFEATURE>()
            ;

 Mapper.CreateMap<SchufaFeature, CFSCHUFAFEATURE>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DATE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetDate(src.date)))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AMOUNT, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.amount.amount))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AMOUNTCUR, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.amount.currency))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.NUMBEROFINSTALLEMENTS, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => TryParseToInt(src.numberOfInstallments)))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.INSTALLMENTTYPE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.installmentType))
              ;
```

It is correctly mapping FEATUREWITHOUTBIRTHDATE and OWNFEATURE, but the Include isn't called. When I run debugger the second CreateMap is never called.

I have checked the Documentation [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance) (AutoMapper Github Inheritance) and I still can't understand what I am doing wrong. What might be the problem ? Is it me or is there a bug in this version of AutoMapper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `.ConstructUsing`. In the first version of AutoMapper the Include does not work as expected, switching the order did nothing for me . Below is my source code:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<SchufaFeature, CFSCHUFAFEATURE>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.FEATUREWITHOUTBIRTHDATE, opt => opt.Ignore())
              .ForMember(dest => dest.OWNFEATURE, opt => opt.Ignore())
              .ForMember(dest => dest.DATE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetDate(src.date)))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.NUMBEROFINSTALLEMENTS, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => TryParseToInt(src.numberOfInstallments)))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.INSTALLMENTTYPE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.installmentType))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.AMOUNT, opt => opt.Ignore())
              .AfterMap((dto, cfschufafeature) => { Mapper.Map(dto.amount, cfschufafeature); })
            ;

        Mapper.CreateMap<SchufaTextFeature, CFSCHUFAFEATURE>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.FEATUREWITHOUTBIRTHDATE, opt => opt.Ignore())
              .ForMember(dest => dest.OWNFEATURE, opt => opt.Ignore())
            ;

        //include does not work in this AutoMapper version as expected, that is why we use ConstructUsing
        Mapper.CreateMap<SchufaBaseFeature, CFSCHUFAFEATURE>()
              .ConstructUsing(feature =>
              {
                  var schufaFeature = feature as SchufaFeature;
                  var schufaTextFeature = feature as SchufaTextFeature;
                  CFSCHUFAFEATURE result = new CFSCHUFAFEATURE();

                  if (schufaFeature != null)
                      Mapper.Map(schufaFeature, result);

                  if (schufaTextFeature != null)
                      Mapper.Map(schufaTextFeature, result);

                  return result;
              })
              .ForMember(dest => dest.FEATUREWITHOUTBIRTHDATE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetSpecified(EnumToBool(src.featureWithoutBirthdate), src.featureWithoutBirthdateSpecified)))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.OWNFEATURE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetSpecified(EnumToBool(src.ownFeature), src.ownFeatureSpecified)))
            ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to switch the order in which you create maps. Include has a....feature in which it checks existing maps for configuration. If that existing map isn't there yet, you'll need to switch the order.

This is all fixed in 5.0 of course but you're stuck :)

Comment: I could not solve the problem with Include. Even playing with the order gets me always the same result.